# Spring boot actuator health endpoint caching is not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, actuator

I have below configuration in my application. Now When I am calling health endpoint of my application then it is not returning cached response.

```yaml
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: 'health'
      base-path: /
  endpoint:
    health:
      cache:
        time-to-live: "120s"
      enabled: true
```

I have provided above configurations and called the endpoint if certain dependent health indicator is down then overall health of application becomes down but health indicator takes sometime to respond hence I provided this configuration so as it will return cached health response but it is not providing cached health response.
I am using spring boot and actuator version 2.7.14